# Send data from field outside a form multip

Tags: php, html

I have two input elements with a `type="date"` outside form and I want to send these dates to form when I press submit inside the form; this my code but it does not work.

```html
<form action="a.php" id="form">
  <input id="something" type="text">
  <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
<form action="b.php" id="form">
  <input id="something" type="text">
  <input type="submit" value="send"> 
</form>
<form action="c.php" id="form">
  <input value="send">
</form>

<input type="date" name="from" form='form'> 
<input type="date" name="to" form='form'>
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by 'it does not work'

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with javascript , if you add hidden inputs to send date values and add method(you forgot use method) like this:

```
<form method="post" action='a.php' id='form'>
    <input type="hidden" name="from">
    <input type="hidden" name="to">
    <input id="something" type="text">
    <input type="submit" value="send" onclick="date();">
</form>

<form method="post" action='b.php'  id='form'>
    <input type="hidden" name="from">
    <input type="hidden" name="to">
    <input id="something" type="text">
    <input type="submit" value="send" onclick="date();"> 
</form>

<form method="post" action='c.php'  id='form'>
    <input type="hidden" name="from">
    <input type="hidden" name="to">
    <input type="submit" value="send" onclick="date();">
</form>
      <input type="date" id="from" form='form'> 
      <input type="date" id="to" form='form'>
```

and if you add javascript codes to change hidden input values to date values like this:

```
<script>
function date(){
for (let index = 0; index < document.forms.length; index++) {
  document.forms[index].elements[0].value=document.getElementById("from").value;
  document.forms[index].elements[1].value=document.getElementById("to").value;
}
}
</script>
```

you can send your values , you can write to page with your action php like this:

```
<?php
echo($_POST["from"]);
echo "<br>";
echo($_POST["to"]);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your current solution you have multiple forms that all have the same `id`. HTML is very forgiving but associating an `input` element with a form using a `form` attribute requires the form’s `id` to be unique.

I do not know your use case but if you wanted to check which submit button was pressed, you can give them a `name` attribute instead.